# Performance issues when Running UPDATE and INSERT queries from different services

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have performance issues when I run frequent/bulk INSERT queries and UPDATE queries from different Windows Services on the same table. Using C# and SQL Server.

I use the same connection strings but I run the queries on separate programs.
What would be the best approach to fix this?

I thought I may use stored procedures to make the queries instead of many INSERT and UPDATEs.

Or probably there is a way to check when a table is occupied by another process and to wait a bit?

When I stop one of the services, the speed of the queries on the UPDATE service become more than twice faster.

Queries are something like this:

ON service1:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, First, Last)
VALUES
('Fred', 'Smith'),
('John', 'Smith'),
('Michael', 'Smith'),
('Robert', 'Smith');
```

On service 2

```
UPDATE table1
SET First = 'Alfred'
WHERE id IN (1, 3, 100, 34 ....);
```

Table1 follows a QUEUE model.
Service 1 inserts 10 records.
Service 2 takes the last elements of the queue from the same table and after some calculations UPDATEs the information back. This happens once every 2-3 seconds on both services.

The main problem is that it is difficult to synchronize them. So probably one query on the same table takes an amount of time but at the same time the other service starts executing his queries so because of this overhead the overall time is slow.

Comment: Performance issues relating to SQL Server are not generic... you have to investigate the specific situation and capture the execution plan to determine what is going on. As such a generic question there is nothing we can offer.

Comment: The question is about a generic approach based on experience not a piece of code. I mean we all before or later have to deal with this situation.

Comment: Um, no, not at all. The **only** way to come up with a performant solution is to measure the performance and be specific about the exact queries being used. Well thats not quite true, you can randomly try things and see if they help - but thats not very productive.

Comment: I added some more information

Comment: We need an execution plan - the queries themselves don't tell us anything.

Comment: When you are experiencing a slow query, I suggest you use `sp_whoisactive` (or some other method) to inspect waits.

Comment: Where does service 2 get the ids from? Maybe that's the slow part.

Comment: it makes a select with TOP 10 first. I verified. it's not the slow part. The update query is the problem takes almost 5-6 seconds even with max 50-60 ids but when i stop service 1 is damn fast.